# how to remove a field from tuple in apache pig

Tags: apache-pig

i have a code as follow:

**`B_t= LOAD 'test.csv' USING PigStorage('\t') as (id:chararray,usr_id:chararray,weed:chararray,ip:chararray);`**

in above, i have field with name weed, i would like remove this field from record with **filter command** without use codes as follow:

**`B_f = FOREACH B_t GENERATE id , usr_id, ip`**

or

**`B_t= LOAD 'test.csv' USING PigStorage('\t')  $0 as id, ....;`**

have anyone idea???

Comment: FILTER is used to filter records from a dataset and not used to remove columns.

Comment: Thanks, are you have UDFs for delete weed field from record automatedly???

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically"? FOREACH statement, as you have put it, will do it. If you mean remove the field during LOAD, I don't know. It could be possible. But, I don't think it is worth to bother with writing complex code just to achieve that, while it can be done with a simple FOREACH statement.

Answer (score 0):

Why in the world u want to use Filter only. Filter is used emit the fields based on condition, not remove the entire field. Foreach -- Generate is the best way.

Comment: Thanks Jahar, but for my work, I need automate delete weed field from my record, when I use Foreach command, I need manually correct the field.  make sense???